# Bundler install - could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack" - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set up ruby on rails to start studying it but I keep getting this error when I run bundle install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2.0) was resolved to 5.2.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)

    simple_form (~> 3.0.2) was resolved to 3.0.4, which depends on
      actionpack (~> 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2.0)

Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.2.0)' in any of the sources.
```

My Gemfile is this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Can somebody help me out?
I'm really new to rails, in fact I'm trying to start learning it, so I have no clue on how to solve this.

Comment: Delete file `gemfile.lock` then do a `bundle install` again. If it fails, kill `gemfile.lock` again and version your gems differently : `gem 'rails', '= 5.2.0'` `gem 'simple_form'` (no version for this gem)

Comment: Hi @Maxence, thanks for you reply. Unfortunately it didn't work. I had already tried deleting gemfile.lock and setting those versions for the gems didn't work. Any other idea? I'm still getting this actionpack error.

Comment: Try killing the `git_source` line. And version as per my previous comment then bundle install again.

Comment: Still getting the same errors, and a bunch more now, @Maxence. I was so excited to start learning rails, but this is such a turn off.

Comment: Try a `bundle update`

Comment: No luck, bundle update gives me the same error

Comment: Try uninstalling all gems `gem uninstall -aIx`, delete the gemfile lock and bundle again `bundle install`

Comment: Can everyone suggesting to "delete everything and start again" please **stop**? Read the error message. It states that there is an incompatibility between the rails and simple_form versions. If you think that the error message is unclear, perhaps you could raise this with the bundler team, and suggest a better format. Personally, I think it's perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that **devise** and **simple_form** gems are outdated and not compatible with the current version of rails.

You could try to install newer versions like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.5.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

then run `bundle install`

Also consider updating the **haml** gem if you want:

`gem 'haml', '~> 5.0.4'` instead of `gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'`

then run `bundle update`

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks MibraDev, you saved me time and effort.

Comment: not work, my part of gemfile is: gem 'devise', '~> 4.5', github: 'heartcombo/devise', branch: 'main'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'devise_token_auth', '0.1.43'